# How to sample a binary output with a fixed number of events (i.e. 1) in R?

Tags: r, random

Suppose I have a data frame like:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(x=rbinom(100,1,0.9), y=rbinom(100,1,0.95))
```

What I wanted is to sample a subset,`df_sub`, from `df` where the number of rows with both `x==1` and `y==1` equals 5 regardless the total number of rows of `df_sub` like:

```
## index <- sample(1:nrow(df),..,replace = FALSE)
df_sub <- df[index,]
df_sub
    x y
1   1 1
2   1 1
3   1 1
4   1 0
5   0 1
6   1 1
7   1 1
```

As you can see, in the df_sub, the number of rows with `x==1` & `y==1` equals `5` while the total number of rows equals `7`. I would like to sample the original `df` with fixed number of `5` with `x==1` & `y==1`  regardless the actual number of row of `df_sub`.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `rep` with `sample`

```
n_events <- 20
total_len <- 70
n_zero_events <- total_len - n_events
v1 <- sample(rep(c(1, 0), c(n_events, n_zero_events)))
> sum(v1)
[1] 20
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! How to sample from fixed vector `v`?

Comment: I revised my question so that it's much closer to my real issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A base R one-liner using `sample` + `rep` + `replace`

```
> sample(replace(rep(0, 100), 1:20, 1))
  [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 [38] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [75] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

For the updated question, we can use `data.table` to perform a self-join to find all to/from indices that meet the criterion. Then we sample from those indices.

```
library(data.table)

subsample <- function(n = 1L, dt, agg) {
  idx <- dt[
    # set the row number and the cumulative count that meet the criterion
    , `:=`(r = .I, z = cumsum(x*y))
  ][
    # set the look-back for the self-join
    , `:=`(z1 = z - agg, z2 = c(0, first(z, -1)))
  ][
    # self-join
    dt, on = .(z2 = z1), nomatch = 0
  ][
    # get the row indices for each row pair that meets the criterion
    , .(idx = .(r:i.r)), seq_along(r)
  ][[2]] # keep just the indices
  # reset dt
  dt[, 3:6 := NULL]
  # check that all the indices are valid (can be deleted, since they always are)
  if (any(vapply(idx, function(x) sum(rowSums(dt[x]) == 2L), integer(1)) != agg)) stop("invalid sample")
  lapply(sample(idx, n, TRUE), function(x) dt[x])
}

set.seed(123)
df <- data.table(x = rbinom(30, 1, 0.8), y = rbinom(30, 1, 0.9))
df_sub <- subsample(10L, df, 5L)
df_sub[[1]]
#>     x y
#>  1: 1 0
#>  2: 1 1
#>  3: 0 1
#>  4: 0 1
#>  5: 1 1
#>  6: 1 1
#>  7: 0 1
#>  8: 1 1
#>  9: 1 1
#> 10: 0 1

set.seed(123)
df <- data.table(x = rbinom(100,1,0.9), y = rbinom(100,1,0.95))
df_sub <- subsample(10L, df, 5L)
df_sub[[1]]
#>    x y
#> 1: 1 1
#> 2: 1 1
#> 3: 0 1
#> 4: 1 1
#> 5: 1 0
#> 6: 1 1
#> 7: 1 1
```